# Quantum Mechanics Spectral theorem proof

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators, mathematics

Has anyone an idea how to prove the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem)
$A = \sum_{i} \lambda_i P_{\lambda_{i}}$.

Starting from $A|\Psi_{i}\rangle=\lambda_{i}|\Psi_{i}\rangle$ or what ever?

Comment: What do $A$ and $P_{\lambda_i}$ mean? This doesn't seem to me to be the spectral theorem - the spectral theorem states: Let $A$ be a self-adjoint compact operator on a finite-dimensional Hilbert space. Then the eigenvectors of $A$ form an orthonormal basis of the Hilbert space on which $A$ acts, and all eigenvectors of $A$ are real.

Comment: Also, the statement of the spectral theorem (and its proof along with it) is very different if the Hilbert space on which $A$ acts is finite-dimensional or infinite-dimensional. Which one are you interested in?

Comment: The difficulty of the proof of the spectral theorem depends on whether the Hilbert space is finite-dimensional or infinite-dimensional, and, if the latter, on precisely what assumptions (boundedness, compactness, etc.) the operator is taken to satisfy. For the finite-dimensional case, a proof is found in any advanced linear algebra textbook. For infinite dimensionality, see any textbook on functional analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can express each vector of the Hilbert Space as a linear combination of the basis vectors with complex numbers $c_{n}$

\begin{align} |\Psi\rangle=\sum_{n} c_{n}|\Psi_{n}\rangle \end{align}

By applying $\langle\Psi_{m}|$ on both sides of the above equation, we get:

$$ \langle\Psi_{m}|\Psi\rangle=\sum_{n} c_{n} \langle\Psi_{m}|\Psi_{n}\rangle$$
Where $\langle\Psi_{m}|\Psi_{n}\rangle=\delta_{mn}$

Thus the coefficients $c_{n}$ are given by:
$$c_{n}=\langle\Psi_{n}|\Psi\rangle$$

Inserting it in our first equation we get:
 $$|\Psi\rangle=\sum_{n} \langle\Psi_{n}|\Psi\rangle|\Psi_{n}\rangle$$

Since $\langle\Psi_{n}|\Psi\rangle$ is a scalar we can move it to the right, so the equation becomes as follows:
$$|\Psi\rangle=\sum_{n} |\Psi_{n}\rangle\langle\Psi_{n}|\Psi\rangle$$

From the above equation we can deduce that:

$$\sum_{n} |\Psi_{n}\rangle\langle\Psi_{n}|=I$$ Where I is the identity operator. Applying your operator $A$ on both sides of the above equation, we get:

$$ \sum_{n} A|\Psi_{n}\rangle\langle\Psi_{n}|=AI$$
But $AI=A$, and substituting $A|\Psi_{n}\rangle=\lambda_{n}|\Psi_{n}\rangle$ in the above equation, we get:
$$ \sum_{n} \lambda_{n}|\Psi_{n}\rangle\langle\Psi_{n}|=A$$

By definition we have the projection operator to be $P_{n}:=|\Psi_{n}\rangle\langle\Psi_{n}|$. Substituting in the above equation we get:

$$ \sum_{n} \lambda_{n}P_{n}=A$$

This completes the proof.

Comment: This assumes that the eigenvectors of $A$ form an orthonormal basis, which is a large part of the (finite dimensional) spectral theorem.